# Keyboard and tracking not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, laptop

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Toshiba Satellite L50-A-18T laptop and everything went smoothly except when I noticed that neither the keyboard nor the track pad worked, only external keyboards and mouses. I have tried to look for a solution but no luck. This only happens when I boot into Ubuntu, if I boot into windows the keyboard and track pad work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using a chuwi aerobook, had the same problem, tried most of the available solutions online and patches to no effect. I then reinstalled 20.4 to find keyboard stopped working again after half day.

As it turns out, after recovery mode boot, keyboard / track-pad work again, although lost control of screen brightness. :)

Waiting for a more 'permanent' solution.

Comment: Did you found a solution ?

Comment: Yeah, it's working. I boot to GRUB and select previous kernel version rather than default. 

Go to GNU GRUBfrom There if i select 'advanced options' instead of the default and boot from Linux 5.4.0-42-generic i have access to all keyboard and trackpad features. There may be more permanent solutions. 



How to go to GRUB
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time

Comment: For me the solution was:
`echo 'blacklist intel_vbtn' >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, this module disable keyboard / mouse thinking the laptop was a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried reinstalling the drivers and updating kernel but didn't help. So I went to the BIOS configuration and checked if the mouse pointer worked there. Initially I couldn't see the cursor in the BIOS menu but I tried to enable the mouse pointer by pressing `Fn + F5` (might be different in your case) and the mouse cursor started to appear and worked in the BIOS menu. I simply restarted my system after that and logged into Ubuntu and the touchpad worked.